# Is there a way to prevent Firebase Realtime Database from downloading JSON item names?

Tags: json, database, firebase-realtime-database

Basically I have a leaderboard that shows the top 50 player's scores. Following Firebase's best practice guidelines I flattened out the data and store the leaderboard scores separate from the player data. However data download is higher than I was expecting (3.62kb for 50 scores). Here is an example of one of these scores entries.

```
    "wgstgJIaVcbdOFvTLIk0VyhO77" : {
      "display_name" : "FakeName7",
      "high_score" : 4
    },
```

I think the data usage is coming from the user id (wgstgJIaVcbdOFvTLIk0VyhO77) This doesn't actually need to be downloaded, but I need to keep it there because I use it in my security rules to allow you to only update your score. Also display name isnt unique so I cant use that as a key.

I understand that using shorter key names (display_name -> n) will help as well.

```
  Path         │ Total   │ Count │ Average │
├──────────────┼─────────┼───────┼─────────┤
│ /leaderboard │ 3.62 kB │ 1     │ 3.62 kB
```

If anyone has a better way to structure this type of data I am all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase's API responses are in JSON format (as your original question clearly states) and providing keys & values is part of the JSON spec. In theory there is a BJSON format (Binary JSON), which saves lots of space both in-transit and in storage, but you have no control what format Firebase's API uses.

- Your only option is to shorten the key names, while I **strongly**
  advise you to be careful with any attempts to shorten certain property values,
  say for example, the user ID values (e.g. trying to implement integer
  IDs, etc.) as this could have security implications.
- Another thing to consider - if you happen to have UTF-8 code points (non-Latin
  characters) in your data values, they will be encoded in JSON and
  their encoded representation will take even more space.
- If you need more "compact" API response you shall consider different
  backend implementation with RESTful API. Just keep in mind that Firebase have lots of limitations. Easy to start, very difficult to implement more complex data-retrieval logic.

Last, but not least - 3.62kb for 50 scores is quite OK even on slow connection. Ask yourself if its worth spending too much time for micro-optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to get a list of just the values of a number of nodes, without also getting the corresponding keys.

The only thing you can consider is using shorter keys, for both the child nodes (`"wgstgJIaVcbdOFvTLIk0VyhO77`") and the property names (`"display_name"`, `"high_score"`).

Comment: Hey Frank thanks for your response. I have already reduced the names down as I mentioned in the end of my original question. Also if you read my question again I need to keep my key name because I use it for security so that only the user can write to their high score node. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: That leaves the first line of my answer then: There is no API to get a list of just the values of a number of nodes, without also getting the corresponding keys.